# I want to add only integer values in a given string

Tags: php, arrays, string, integer, character

```
<?php

$str = "1,2,3,4,b,6,c,7,8,f,9";

?>
```

I want to add only integer values in the above string... Can anyone suggest me an answer ? I tried explode function which will explode the character and return the integer values... But I failed to do so...

Comment: can you show me your code?

Comment: I've added formatting to your code, it wasn't visible otherwise

Answer (score 2):

You need to split them up, filter anything that's not numeric out, then add them:

```
$chars = explode(',', $str);
$chars = array_filter($chars, 'is_numeric');
echo array_sum($chars); // 40
```

Comment: Incidentally, the result for this example is the same without the `array_filter`. I guess `array_sum` converts the values to numeric and the letters become zeros.